# Foreach mysql select result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a search field like if I search "Spinach, Watermelon", it will explode the input by ",", and run MySQL search database. That means the SQL will run as

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE vegetable LIKE '%Spinach%' OR fruits LIKE '%Spinach%'

SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE vegetable LIKE '%Watermelon%' OR fruits LIKE '%Watermelon%'
```

My database table data looks something like this :

```
id  Vegetable  fruits
----------------------
1   Spinach    Apple
2   Cucumber   Orange
3   Spinach    Watermelon
```

The result of each id only can come out once.

```
<php>
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keyword = explode(",", $keywords);
foreach($keyword as $keys=>$select)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE vegetable LIKE '%keyword %' OR fruits LIKE '%keyword %'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {    
       $vege = $rs["vegetable"];
       $fruits = $rs["fruits"];
   }
}

<html>
<form method=post>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEARCH..." value="<?=$keywords?>">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Your table has vegetable and fruits tied to the same ID?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and what's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using `REGEXP` with an alternation instead of `LIKE`, then here is a straightforward approach:

```
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keywords = preg_replace("/,\s*/", "|", $keywords);
$where = "[[:<:]](" . $keywords . ")[[:>:]]";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$sql .= "WHERE vegetable REGEXP '" . $where . "' OR fruits REGEXP '" . $where . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $vege = $rs["vegetable"];
    $fruits = $rs["fruits"];
}
```

Assuming you passed in the keywords search string `"Spinach, Watermelon"`, the above script would generate this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    vegetable REGEXP '[[:<:]](Spinach|Watermelon)[[:>:]]' OR
    fruits REGEXP '[[:<:]](Spinach|Watermelon)[[:>:]]';
```

Honestly the best approach here would be to use `LIKE` or `REGEXP` with a prepared statement.  If you do choose to use my approach, then you absolutely should sterilize the incoming CSV string to make sure it has only alphanumeric characters, comma, and whitespace in it.

Comment: How about if is AND condition?

Comment: You would use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]Spinach[[:>:]]' AND REGEXP '[[:<:]]Watermelon[[:>:]]'` ...but you might want to open a new question, as this one has already been answered.

Comment: Ok, i had open a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762616/regular-expression-mysql-with-and-operator

Answer (score 1):

Hitting database in for loop is not a good approach, You can build you query like this:

```
<?php
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keyword = explode(",", $keywords);
$sqlWhere = '';
foreach($keyword as $keys=>$select)
{
   $sqlWhere .= "LIKE '%$select%' OR";
}
$sqlWhere = rtrim($sqlWhere, "OR");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table " . $sqlWhere;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{    
       $vege = $rs["vegetable"];
       $fruits = $rs["fruits"];
}    
?>
```

Comment: Not injection safe (though neither is my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will print your records must.

```
<php>
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keyword = explode(",", $keywords);
for($i=0; $i<count($keyword); $i++)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE vegetable LIKE '%" . $keyword[$i] . "%' OR fruits LIKE '%" . " . $keyword[$i] . " . "%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($rs); exit; 
}

?>
<html>
<form method=post>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEARCH..." value="<?=$keywords?>">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your probelm is "*The result of each id only can come out once.".

So better make one Query:

```
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keyword = explode(",", $keywords);
$where = [];
foreach($keyword as $keys)
{
   $where[] = "vegetable LIKE '%".$keys." %' OR fruits LIKE '%".$keys." %'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ".(empty($where) ? '' : implode(' OR ', $where));
```

so you have one query an one result set.

Dont forgett to escape your keywords.