# Regular Expression mysql with AND operator

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex

I had create a search field and if i search "Spinach, Watermelon", it will explode the input by ",", and run MySQL search database. That means the SQL will run as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(vegetable LIKE '%Spinach%' OR fruits LIKE '%Spinach%') AND (vegetable LIKE '%Watermelon%' OR fruits LIKE '%Watermelon%')
```

My database table data looks something like this :

```
id  Vegetable  fruits
----------------------
1   Spinach    Apple
2   Cucumber   Orange
3   Spinach    Watermelon
```

The result of each id only can come out once.

```
<php>
$keywords = trim($_REQUEST['keyword']);
$keywords = preg_replace("/,\s*/", "|", $keyword);
$where = "[[:<:]](" . $keywords . ")[[:>:]]";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$sql .= "WHERE vegetable REGEXP '" . $where . "' OR fruits REGEXP '" . $where . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $vege = $rs["vegetable"];
    $fruits = $rs["fruits"];
}

</php>


<html>
<form method=post>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SEARCH..." value="<?=$keywords?>">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your specific question you want to know about? As it stands, this an explanation of what you were doing and/or intended it to do, but there is no clear problem statement.

Comment: I want to generate a mysql query like below with regular expression, SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(vegetable LIKE '%Spinach%' OR fruits LIKE '%Spinach%') AND (vegetable LIKE '%Watermelon%' OR fruits LIKE '%Watermelon%')

Comment: Are you assuming the Asker does not specify whether 'Spinach' is a Fruit versus a Vegetable?  And your table can only have exactly one fruit paired with exactly one vegetable?  Both requirements seem strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the literal MySQL query using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    (vegetable REGEXP '[[:<:]]Spinach[[:>:]]' OR fruits REGEXP '[[:<:]]Spinach[[:>:]]') AND
    (vegetable REGEXP '[[:<:]]Watermelon[[:>:]]' OR fruits REGEXP '[[:<:]]Watermelon[[:>:]]');
```

Comment: Should i still use the preg_replace?    $keywords = preg_replace("/,\s*/", "|", $keyword);

Comment: I don't know because this question does not manifest a need for that.  Comparing one column against many OR possibilities would need my previous answer.

Comment: Cause i want make the condition is based on what user input, for example if user input Spinach,Watermelon,Rice, then behind the WHERE mysql will add one more condition ---> AND ((vegetable REGEXP '[[:<:]]Rice[[:>:]]' OR fruits REGEXP '[[:<:]]Rice[[:>:]]')